# JAVA - JLayer - Squeaky sound and some choppiness, streaming from SHOUTcast

Tags: java, shoutcast

I made an quick app in Java to see if I was able to connect to my SHOUTcast and stream from it, and it worked with the following code:

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import javazoom.jl.player.Player;

public class Start {

    public static void main(String[] args){

         JFrame window = new JFrame();
         window.setVisible(true);
         window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        try {
             URL url=new URL("http://devllama.pwnz.org:88");
             Socket socket=new Socket(url.getHost(), url.getPort());
             OutputStream os=socket.getOutputStream();
             String user_agent = "BrennynSabar/0.5";
             String req="GET / HTTP/1.0\r\nuser-agent: "+user_agent+"\r\nIcy-MetaData: 1\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n";
             os.write(req.getBytes());
             InputStream is=socket.getInputStream();
             BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
             Player player = new Player(bis);
             player.play();
        } 
        catch (Exception e){
             e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

It connects and plays, the audio sounds pretty good, but theres a random squeaking sound in the background, I know its not the SHOUTcast server because you can connect using VLC or something and it wont be there. Also once in a while, the song gets choppy, but I am pretty sure its my connection. Any help will be be awesome, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

An optional part of a shoutcast stream is periodic metadata blocks.

At the beginning of the fake HTTP connection there are headers which this code is currently passing off as MP3 data.

One of those headers may be a header "icy-metaint" set to N where N is the number of bytes between each metadata block. If the header is missing then the metadata blocks aren't present. The first byte of the metadata block contains the length in 16 byte increments of metadata (eg: 1 means 16 bytes of metadata). The metadata is then padded with nulls at he end if it doesn't come out to an even 16 bytes.

Your MP3 decoder is reading these metadata blocks as MP3 data and it comes out as blips.

Comment: I've only written the opposite of this (the streaming server). You're going to need to parse the headers and do some more fancy stream copying instead of blindly passing the raw stream to the MP3 decoder.